# Add new ports like 8081 in cloudflare

Tags: python, django, port, cpanel, cloudflare

I have two Django project running on port `8080` and `8081` with named domain name abc.com

Now we added our website to Cloudflare so abc.com with new IP with port 8080 is working fine

But, on port 8081 we can access it via the only `original_host_ip` and not the domainname.com

i.e

```
abc.com:8080 WORKING
a.b.c.d:8081 WORKING
```

I tested it via

`Test-NetConnection a.b.c.d -port 8081`

`Test-NetConnection abc.com -port 8081`

```
abc.com:8081 NOTWORKING ->Remote address cloudflare
a.b.c.d:8081 WORKING    ->Remote address a.b.c.d
```

[image]

So I thought it is maybe due to the firewall of Cloudflare that it is not accepting port 8081

So I want to know how to add a new port to Cloudflare like port 8081.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-) this appears to be impossible without Cloudflare Spectrum which is only available on paid plans. This explains why 8080 works but 8081 does not.

If possible consider using one of the other non-standard ports instead:

HTTP:
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095

HTTPS:
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443