# socket.io port 3002 timeout after using Cloudflare

Tags: socket.io, cloudflare

I'm using socket.io for chat in my website. Yesterday i changed to DNS to cloudflare after the port 3002 gives time out error

Socket.io

```
server.listen('3002', function(){
  console.log('listening on port');
});
```

Error :

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3002 is not a supported port for standard Cloudflare, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105401/add-new-ports-like-8081-in-cloudflare/66110660#66110660).

Additionally you should take a look at cloudflare's site with respect to [support for websockets](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Using-Cloudflare-with-WebSockets).

Comment: yes. thanks i used 8443 port and its working